# Can two unvaccinated puppies play together?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

Can an unvacinated puppy who hasnt gone outside play with another unvaccinated puppy ?  I just got a 2 month old puppy (unvaccinated) i was planning on going over to a friends house whos dog is also unvaccinated both havent been outside at all .

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of the linked broader question.  Essentially the answer there say, there are risks but your choice of a friends house is the safest choice.